# The client code aborts abruptly while connecting to server in C++ through winsock API

Tags: c++, winsock

Recently I was making multi-threaded server application which is capable of connecting to multiple clients. But, when I ran the client application, some run-time library exception occurred with "Debug Assertion Failed" dialog. I am not able to find out the exact reason for this error. I am making use of Winsock API in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. Can someone please help me to look out for a solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Client:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

//DECLARATIONS
//error trapping signals
#define SIGINT 2
#define SIGKILL 9
#define SIGQUIT 3
// SOCKETS
SOCKET sock, client;

void s_handle(int s)
{
    if (sock)
        closesocket(sock);
    if (client)
        closesocket(client);
    WSACleanup();
    Sleep(10);
    cout << "EXIT SIGNAL :" << s;
    exit(0);
}


void s_cl(char *a, int x)
{
    cout << a;
    s_handle(x + 1000);
}


int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    //SetConsoleTitle(".:: Basic Echo Client By KOrUPt 07 ::. ");


    //Declarations
    DWORD poll;
    int res, i = 1, port = 999;
    char buf[100];
    char msg[100] = "";
    char ip[15];
    WSADATA data;

    signal(SIGINT, s_handle);
    signal(SIGKILL, s_handle);
    signal(SIGQUIT, s_handle);

    cout << "\t\tEcho This is a Client";

    cout << "\n\n\n\t\tEnter IP to connect to: ";
    gets(ip);

    sockaddr_in ser;
    sockaddr addr;


    ser.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ser.sin_port = htons(123);                    //Set the port
    ser.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);      //Set the address we want to connect to

    memcpy(&addr, &ser, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

    res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &data);      //Start Winsock
    cout << "\n\nWSAStartup"
        << "\nVersion: " << data.wVersion
        << "\nDescription: " << data.szDescription
        << "\nStatus: " << data.szSystemStatus << endl;

    if (res != 0)
        s_cl("WSAStarup failed", WSAGetLastError());

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);       //Create the socket
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        s_cl("Invalid Socket ", WSAGetLastError());
    else if (sock == SOCKET_ERROR)
        s_cl("Socket Error)", WSAGetLastError());
    else
        cout << "Socket Established" << endl;



    res = connect(sock, &addr, sizeof(addr));               //Connect to the server
    if (res != 0)
    {
        s_cl("SERVER UNAVAILABLE", res);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nConnected to Server: ";
        memcpy(&ser, &addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR));
    }

    char RecvdData[100] = "";
    int ret;

    while (true)
    {
        strcpy(buf, "");
        cout << "\nEnter message to send ->\n";
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);


        Sleep(5);
        res = send(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

        if (res == 0)
        {
            //0==other side terminated conn
            printf("\nSERVER terminated connection\n");
            Sleep(40);
            closesocket(client);
            client = 0;
            break;
        }
        else if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            //-1 == send error
            printf("Socket error\n");
            Sleep(40);
            s_handle(res);
            break;
        }

        ret = recv(sock, RecvdData, sizeof(RecvdData), 0);
        if (ret > 0)
        {
            cout << endl << RecvdData;
            strcpy(RecvdData, "");
        }
    }

    closesocket(client);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Server:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

// our thread for recving commands
DWORD WINAPI receive_cmds(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    cout << "thread created\r\n";

    // set our socket to the socket passed in as a parameter   
    SOCKET current_client = (SOCKET)lpParam;

    // buffer to hold our recived data
    char buf[100];
    // buffer to hold our sent data
    char sendData[100];
    // for error checking 
    int res;

    // our recv loop
    while (true)
    {
        res = recv(current_client, buf, sizeof(buf), 0); // recv cmds

        Sleep(2);

        if (res == 0)
        {
            //MessageBox(0, "error", "error", MB_OK);
            closesocket(current_client);
            ExitThread(0);
        }

        if (strstr(buf, "hello"))
        { // greet this user
            cout << "\nrecived hello cmd";

            strcpy(sendData, "hello, greetings from server\n");
            Sleep(2);
            send(current_client, sendData, sizeof(sendData), 0);
        }
        else if (strstr(buf, "bye"))
        { // dissconnected this user
            cout << "\nrecived bye cmd\n";

            strcpy(sendData, "cya\n");
            Sleep(2);
            send(current_client, sendData, sizeof(sendData), 0);

            // close the socket associted with this client and end this thread
            closesocket(current_client);
            ExitThread(0);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(sendData, "Invalid cmd\n");
            Sleep(2);
            send(current_client, sendData, sizeof(sendData), 0);
        }

        // clear buffers
        strcpy(sendData, "");
        strcpy(buf, "");
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Starting up multi-threaded TCP server");

    // our masterSocket(socket that listens for connections)
    SOCKET sock;

    // for our thread
    DWORD thread;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    sockaddr_in server;

    // start winsock
    int ret = WSAStartup(0x101, &wsaData); // use highest version of winsock avalible

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // fill in winsock struct ... 
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(123); // listen on telnet port 23

    // create our socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // bind our socket to a port(port 123) 
    if (bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) != 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // listen for a connection  
    if (listen(sock, 5) != 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // socket that we sendrecv data on
    SOCKET client;

    sockaddr_in from;
    int fromlen = sizeof(from);

    // loop forever 
    while (true)
    {
        // accept connections
        client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &fromlen);
        cout << "Client connected\r\n";

        // create our recv_cmds thread and parse client socket as a parameter
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, receive_cmds, (LPVOID)client, 0, &thread);
    }

    // shutdown winsock
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    // exit
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO.  In order to get help, you need to complete your question by using your debugger and explaining where exactly in the client or server code the debug assertion is trigerred, as well as the test data you're using.

Comment: @Christophe How to attach the screenshot? A dialog box appears with the error. Don't know how exactly to tell the error.
It says Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
File:f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\winsig.c
Expression: ("Invalid signal or error", 0)

The error is something like this

Comment: If you get this dialog then you should attach debugger (Main menu -> Debug -> Attach to process) and press Retry. It will show the place where the error occurred, call stack, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. Now my code works fine.
I want to send many images instead of normal message. How to do that?